# C++ array - how to display the names?

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have a number of participants of diving competition and being scored by judges.
I need to display the total scores according to name of the participants.

How do i solve this problem?

```cpp
int scores[5][2], i, j;
int sum =0;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    char name [50];
    cout << "Enter participant's name: ";
    cin >> name; 
    cout<<"Enter scores for " << name <<endl;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        cin>>scores[i][j];
    }
}
    

sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        char name [50];
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            sum += scores[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"Total scores of Participant " << name << " " <<" is "<<sum<<endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You have two variables called `name`. The one in the first loop has the name, the one in the second loop has nothing. You need to combine your two loops into one, or you need to use **one** two dimensional array for the names (like you did for the scores).

Comment: What happens if someone enters a longer name? Use `std::string`.

Comment: You need to store both names and scores, for instance in an array of `struct Participant { std::string name; int scores[2];};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its my first answer here (ever) so I'm very exited an hope it helps! =)

when you wrote "`char name[50]`", you actually made an array of chars (array of single letters), and every cycle in the loop you wrote over that same array(and only the first letter of the a name each time).

I think you meant to create an array of names (strings), you can also do it with `char name[5][50]` but it is easier using the library string.
I believe a better implementation would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int scores[5][2], i, j; int sum =0;
string name [5];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{

    cout << "Enter participant's name: \n";
    cin >> name[i];
    cout<<"Enter scores for " << name[i] <<endl;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)

    {
        cin>>scores[i][j];
    }
}


for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        sum += scores[i][j];
    }
    cout<<"Total scores of Participant " << name[i] << " " <<" is "<<sum<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps, and if you have any questions I would be heppy to try my best and answer! good luck =)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main types of variables, *global* and *local*.

**Global Variables** 
These types of variables can be accessed by child scopes and can be accessed by functions (if its in the global namespace).

```cpp
int global = 0;

{    // This is an empty scope
    int x = global;
}
```

**Local Variables** 
These types of variables are restricted to a single scope, but can be accessed by child scopes. Mostly a variable is called 'local' variable if only one scope owns it.

```cpp
{    // This is an empty scope.
    int local = 0;
}

int global = local;    // You cannot do this because the variable 'local' is a local variable to that empty scope.
```

**What does 'global' and 'local' have to do with my problem?** 
If we take a look at this block of code,

```cpp
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    char name [50];
    cout << "Enter participant's name: ";
    cin >> name; 
    cout<<"Enter scores for " << name <<endl;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        cin>>scores[i][j];
    }
}
```

The variable `name` is local to that `for` loop. Meaning it cannot be accessed outside of that loop. And in the other `for` loop, you declare the `name` variable again. These two variables are two separate variables. Once a variable goes out of scope, its data gets destroyed (assuming that the variable is stack allocated). This means that you have **no way** of getting the name information from the first `name` variable.

**How to solve this?** 
Mark the `name` variable as a *global* variable in that scope,

```cpp
    int scores[5][2], i, j;
    char name [50];
    int sum =0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter participant's name: ";
        cin >> name; 
        cout<<"Enter scores for " << name <<endl;
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            cin>>scores[i][j];
        }
    }
    

    sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            sum += scores[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"Total scores of Participant " << name << " " <<" is "<<sum<<endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Now the second `for` loop can access the `name` variable with the relevant data that you want.

Note: If there isn't a reason to strictly use a raw string array (`char name[50]`), lets say if the name can be longer than 50 characters, use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new struct like this:

```
typedef struct result
{
 string name;
 int vote[2];
}result;
```

It contains a name (more than 49 char if any) and own two votes.

This is an array of five struct as described above.

```
result scores[5];

...
```

simply access to athlete i name and to its score:

```
cout<<"Name :"<<scores[i].name<<" score:"<<scores[i].vote[0]+scores[i].vote[1]<<endl;
```

Comment: Consider adding some explaination to your answer. As it stands at the moment, I don't this will really help the OP, as it is difficult to understand

Comment: @user1781290 Do you like it now ? ;-)